# How do I use google-auth-library in client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api-js-client

I have a frontend service written in React and built with Vite.  I need it to fetch an auth token from `google-auth-library` that it can use to authenticate with the backend.  I'm going through [Google's documentation on service-to-service communication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#gcloud) and it wants me to write code like this:

```js
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library')
const auth = new GoogleAuth();
const audience = '<FRONTEND_HOSTNAME>'
const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(audience)
const clientHeaders = await client.getRequestHeaders()
return clientHeaders['Authorization']
```

When run in the browser, this code fails on the first line with `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.  I do not have `type:module` in my package.json, which is one solution I found while googling around.  I've also tried using Browserify to bundle `google-auth-library`, but it fails in the same place, presumably because the `require` it has a problem with is the one in my code and not in the library.

How do I use this library on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library';
```